# Some sites with wiki-engine in the web for hosting

Tags: web-hosting

Are there any sites in the web like Wikipedia and this site, which have wiki-engine and may be used for hosting? Wikipedia has some troubles nowadays with formulas tags converting, so I want to use the other site.

Comment: Not entirely sure what you're asking but if you want to create your own Wiki site you could try something like [Wikia](http://www.wikia.com/Wikia). Does that help?

Comment: All answers about which Wiki or CMS system to use should be posted in a single place.